# Gsoap Http event callback

Tags: c++, visual-c++, soap, gsoap

I downloaded gSoap and generated source code for wsdl. And I could connect to the server and send the request.

But I can't understand how I can catch http events like bytes sent, bytes recv.
I read this document http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html.

But I can't find what I need. I found function `fsend`. As I understand this function is being executed when we're sending a request to the server. Do I have to do something like this?

```
service.fsend = Custom;
```

Where `Custom` is my callback?

I've found other callback is ffiltersend.
As I understand this function is being runned when request is sending.
I use it.
But I don't understand last parametr in this method is pointer to size_t.
When I get value from this pointer and devide by 2 I get count of my real bytes. Why?

Comment: is bytes send, bytes recv very meaningful to you?

Comment: For me more importnat time of sending, cause I upload file via gSoap... That's why bytes recv for me not to important... And I still don't understand how can I do it....

Answer (score 0):

To obtain statistics on the number of bytes sent, received, and to log the inbound and outbound messages to a file system, use the "logging plugin" that comes with the gSOAP software.

First, register the plugin with:

```
#include "plugin/logging.h" // this file is in the gSOAP distro path
...
soap_register_plugin(soap, logging);
```

Then use these functions to set the logging destinations for inbound and outbound messages:

```
soap_set_logging_inbound(struct soap*, FILE*);
soap_set_logging_outbound(struct soap*, FILE*);
```

where the file descriptor passed as the second argument points to an open file that you can open and close before and after logging.  Use `NULL` as the second argument to disable logging.

To obtain stats, i.e. message size byte counts, use:

```
soap_get_logging_stats(struct soap*, size_t *sent, size_t *recv);
```

where the second and third arguments will be updated by this call.

That's all there is too it.

If you want to use your own message handling callbacks then perhaps a good place to start is to learn from the `plugin/logging.c` file on how that is done. This file is short.